# Rock, Paper Scissors - Accounting for Upper or Lower Case

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am tasked with creating user input for a Rock, Paper, Scissors game.

I am able get the correct output results  for inputting all lowercase inputs. However I am not getting print statements for if one or both (unless they are the same input) is uppercase.

How would I use the `.upper()` and `.lower()` to ensure the code  functions as intended?

```
P1 = input('Enter [R]ock, [P]aper, or [S]cissor' )
print ('Player 1:', P1)

P2 = input('Enter [R]ock, [P]aper, or [S]cissor' )
print ('Player 2:', P2)

if P1 == P2 :
    print('Nobody WINS!')
elif P1 == 's' :
    if P2 == 'r' :
         print('Rock smashes scissors.')
         print('P2 WINS!')
    else :
         print('Scissor cuts paper.')
         print('P1 WINS!')
elif P1 == 'r' :
    if P2 == 'p' :
         print('Paper covers rock.')
         print('P2 WINS!')
    else :
         print('Rock smashes scissors.')
         print('P1 WINS!')
elif P1 == 'p' :
    if P2 == 's' :
         print('Scissor cuts paper.')
         print('P2 WINS!')
    else :
         print('Paper covers rock.')
         print('P1 WINS!')`P1 = input('Enter [R]ock, [P]aper, or [S]cissor' )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
P1 = input('Enter [R]ock, [P]aper, or [S]cissor' ).lower()
print ('Player 1:', P1)

P2 = input('Enter [R]ock, [P]aper, or [S]cissor' ).lower()
print ('Player 2:', P2)
```

If the user enters an uppercase letter, it will be made lowercase by doing what you see above ...